# SetEnvIfNoCase Host: .htaccess to web.config conversion

Tags: php, iis, .htaccess, asp.net, web.config

I have tried IIS Manager and some online conversion tools but I can't figure out how to achieve the following .htaccess rules in a web.config file:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host my-domain.com  nopassreq

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted"
AuthUserFile "/home/my-domain.com/passwd"
require valid-user

Order allow, deny
Allow from env=nopassreq
Satisfy any
```

Basically if the user has come to the site using `my-domain.com` it doesn't ask for authentication, but if it was `my-other-domain.com` or anything else actually, it would ask for authentication.

I have multiple domains pointing to the same cloud instance on Azure, and I need some of those to require authentication and some not.

Comment: It's kind of a non answer, but why not just use Apache?

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no way to use Apache on Azure Cloud Services (not Virtual Machines)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any way to set this up in IIS using URL Redirection rules because the only actions supported are Rewrite, None, Redirect, Custom Response and Abort Request. You can use them to set environment variables that your code could evaluate later though.

Since this setting can be defined on a per site basis, perhaps you'll have better luck implementing some automation using PowerShell cmdlets for IIS. For instance, to toggle anonymous authentication:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.WebServer/security/authentication/AnonymousAuthentication `
        -name enabled -value false -location YourApp
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am not sure how I would go about doing this on Azure Cloud Instances. The easiest thing for me to change is the web.config file as it's just included in the app package and included automatically when instances are scaled up or down.

Answer (score 0):

Tried a bit, not a .net expert, and got this code:

```
<rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
         <rule name="nopassres">
             <match serverVariable="nopassreq" pattern=".*" />
             <action type="Rewrite" value="dontpass" />
             <conditions>
                 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="my\-domain\.com" />
             </conditions>
         </rule>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```